# Menu item not showing on phone having soft menu key

Tags: android, menu

I'm upgrading my old app, where I have used menu item.

Menu item is showing correctly on phones having fixed menu key i.e. 3 dots at the bottom of the phone. But on the phone which shows 'back', 'home' and 'menu' on the screen such as Sony Xperia, menu key is not appearing. But my old apk compiled years ago is working properly.

When I made it years ago manifest file said -
Minimum SDK 8, target SDK 11. Even if I use this target its not showing. Previously I used Eclipse and at present I'm using Android Studio.
I can not use action bar,space constraints. Thanks for help.